# MoCa - Ethernet over Coaxial

Tags: ethernet, coax, modem

This is specifically a high-level hobbyist question, I'm not really looking for schematics or anything of the sort.

To deliver Ethernet over Coaxial, what sort of high-level designs or common issues will I need/face in completing this task? Initial research found that this technology is also referred to as MoCa, see:

[Multimedia over Coax Alliance](http://www.mocalliance.org/)

From my understanding, I need to essentially build two modems.

I'm just looking for a starting point to begin my own research, any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: This question may be closed as being a bit too broad. Sounds like an interesting project however. To start with you should probably define exactly what your scope is, i.e. do you want to implement all of the Ethernet protocol yourself and so on, maybe look at some existing FPGA/microcontroller implementations

Comment: Ethernet was originally implemented over coaxial, first using transceivers attached to the cable and connected to equipment via transceiver cable, then using thinner coax with the transceivers built into the equipment. Read some history?

Comment: Fair enough. Cheers for the help guys, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Begin from reading a datasheet on something like this:

- [Microchip's FastECoax7501](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/FASTECOAX7501)

IMO, it's a good way to meet the technology, including the first time.

To build a modem on this chip, you also need a 100BASE-TX to 100BASE-FX converter/switch IC, but this is not a problem too because there are many solutions on the market today.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. At a $180 AUD price point I wonder how the fully built solutions can be only $100 imported. Any comments on the price?

Comment: Example from Farnell: EQCO-FASTECOAX7501.2 costs about 120 euro per set of two ready-to-run modems. Is it (too?) expensive? IMO, **it is more than good price for a pair of two modems**. Chip itself (EQCO875SC.3) costs about 6,4 euro/chip.

Comment: Thanks, the chip number was what I was looking for. I didn't want to buy a ready-built solution, especially at that price point when I'm not certain it will work for my use case. @$25 AUD that's much more reasonable

Comment: If it's not secret, what is your case?

Comment: Just a hobby project. I'd like to extend networking across my house over the TV Antenna coax. I'm aware you can buy powerline adapters as well, but this sounded like a fun experiment

Comment: Next clarification: Do you need co-existence of services in the cable? I.e. Do you plan to use the cable solely for networking purpose, or need to access both "new" (networking) and "old" (TV) services over single cable?

Comment: That would be ideal yes. Many of the MoCa devices on the market do provide this, see Actiontec ECB2500CK01, although as a stepping stone solutions without this feature would still interest me.